# Julius König's proof of Schröder–Bernstein theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I found that Julius König's proof is short and simple to understand, but Wikipedia only provides a sketch and omits details. Here I present a proof with full detail.

Please have a check on it! Thank you so much!

Theorem:

> Let $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to A$ be injections. Then there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

Proof:

> Without loss of generality, we can safely assume that $A \cap B=\varnothing$.
>
> For any $x \in A \cup B$, we can form a unique sequence by repeatedly applying $f$ and $g$ to go right, and $g^{-1}$ and $f^{-1}$ to go left whenever $g^{-1}(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are defined.
>
> Such sequence looks like: $$\cdots \rightarrow f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)) \rightarrow g^{-1}(x) \rightarrow x \rightarrow f(x) \rightarrow g(f(x)) \rightarrow \cdots$$
>
> For any particular $x$, the sequence may terminate to the left or not, at a point when $f^{-1}$ or $g^{-1}$ is not defined. Since $f$ and $g$ are injective, each $x$ is in exactly one such sequence to within identity (if an element occurs in two sequences, all elements to the left and to the right must be the same in both. So these two sequences are identical). Therefore, the sequences form a partition of $A \cup B$.
>
> Call a sequence an **A-stopper** if it stops at an element of $A$, or a **B-stopper** if it stops at an element of $B$. Otherwise, call it **doubly infinite**. It suffices to generate bijection for each sequence as follows.
>
> 1. **A-stopper**
>
> Let $A_1$ be the set of its elements in $A$, $B_1$ be the set of its elements in $B$.
>
> Let $h:A_1 \to B_1$ such that $h(a)=f(a)$ for all $a \in A_1$.
>
> $h(a_1)=h(a_2) \implies f(a_1)=f(a_2) \implies a_1=a_2$ [Since $f$ is injective] $\implies h$ is injective.
>
> For $b \in B_1$, there exists $x=f^{-1}(b) \in A_1$ [If not, this sequence will stop at $b \in B$, which contradicts to the fact that it is **A-stopper**). $h(x)=f(f^{-1}(b)=b \implies h$ is surjective.
>
> Thus $h:A_1 \to B_1$ is bijective.
>
> 2. **B-stopper**
>
> Let $A_2$ be the set of its elements in $A$, $B_2$ be the set of its elements in $B$.
>
> Let $k:B_2 \to A_2$ such that $k(b)=g(b)$ for all $b \in B_2$.
>
> $k(b_1)=k(b_2) \implies g(b_1)=g(b_2) \implies b_1=b_2$ [Since $g$ is injective] $\implies k$ is injective.
>
> For $a \in A_2$, there exists $y=g^{-1}(a) \in B_2$ [If not, this sequence will stop at $a \in A$, which contradicts to the fact that it is **B-stopper**). $k(y)=g(g^{-1}(a)=a \implies k$ is surjective.
>
> Thus $k:B_2 \to A_2$ is bijective. Then $k^{-1}:A_2 \to B_2$ is bijective.
>
> 3. **Doubly infinite**
>
> Let $A_3$ be the set of its elements in $A$, $B_3$ be the set of its elements in $B$.
>
> Let $t:A_3 \to B_3$ such that $t(a)=f(a)$ for all $a \in A_3$.
>
> $t(a_1)=t(a_2) \implies f(a_1)=f(a_2) \implies a_1=a_2$ [Since $f$ is injective] $\implies t$ is injective.
>
> For $b \in B_3$, there exists $x=f^{-1}(b) \in A_3$ [If not, this sequence will stop at $b \in B$, which contradicts to the fact that it is **doubly infinite**). $t(x)=f(f^{-1}(b)=b \implies t$ is surjective.
>
> Thus $t:A_3 \to B_3$ is bijective.

Comment: I'm too lazy to read the details, but offhand this looks like the "ancestor-descendant" proof, which seems to be the most popular way to prove the Cantor–Bernstein theorem. I didn't know it was  Julius König's invention.

Comment: @bof i found this reference from wikipedia. I'm not sure if it's correct or not :)

Comment: Seems about right! I always thought Tarski's proof (actually I don't know if he proved it but the lemma used is the Tarski Fixed point for morphism of complete lattices) was shorter and simpler to understand. Have you studied it?

Comment: @LeoLerena I have read Tarski's proof too, but it's good to see different approaches and therefore have a wider view of what's going on :)

Comment: Seeing your last comment I think you may enjoy reading [this book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319173672).

Comment: Thank you so much @user170039! Yes, I'm very interested in different proofs of the same theorems. Of course, we have different point of views and maybe learn some novel and useful insights ^^

Comment: @user170039. On the topic of different proofs: The first chapter of the book "Prime Number Records" consists of about 23 different proofs that there is no largest prime, including a topological proof.

Comment: You can find a nice presentation in "Introduction To Topology And Higher Analysis" by Simmons. Regardless of whether $A$ intersects $B,$  for $a\in A$ let  $a\in E$  iff the sequence  $(g^{-1}(a), f^{-1}g^{-1}(a),...)$  stops after an  even  number of terms (including possibly $0$ terms). Let $h(a)=f(a)$  if  $a\in E$ and $h(a)=g^{-1}(a) $ if $a\in A\backslash E.$.... The mnemonic I use to remember it is that if the sequence has  $0$ terms  we must take $h(a)=f(a)$ because  $g^{-1}(a)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you @DanielWainfleet! You actually presented that proof in one of my questions a few months ago ^^

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I actually bookmarked that excellent book in my web browser before :)

Comment: I am trying to understand this proof, and the concept is totally clear to me. But why can we safely assume that the intersection is empty? Is it guaranteed that $f(A\cap B) = A\cap B$?

Comment: @Gecko1111 If $A \cap B$ is not empty, we can use another set $C$ such that $C \cong B$ and $C \cap A = \emptyset$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few flaws that exists not because of a mistake, but because you were sloppy:

> "...the sequences form a partition"

Should be

> "...the range of the sequences form a partition"

Also

> "It suffices to generate bijection for each sequence as follows"

This is correct but needs a proof:

> Let $P$ be the partition, and let $$P_A=\{x\in\mathcal P(\bigcup P)\mid\forall a\in x(a\in A)\land(x\subseteq Q\subseteq\bigcup P\implies(\forall b\in Q\setminus x(b\notin A)))\}\\P_B=\{x\in\mathcal P( \bigcup P)\mid\forall a\in x(a\in B)\land(x\subseteq Q\subseteq\bigcup P\implies(\forall b\in Q\setminus x(b\notin B)))\}$$ in other words: you separate the partition to 2 partitions for $A,B$.
>
> Now, let $f$ be bijective from $P_A$ to $P_B$ such that $f(x)=y\iff x\cup y\in P$, therefore there exists bijective $F_x: x\to f(x)$, thus $G: A\to B$ will be bijective defined as $\bigcup_{x\in P_A}F_x$.

---

Now, apart from this, the proof is good, but (in my opinion) it is easier to prove this theorem assuming $B\subseteq A$ instead of $A\cap B=\emptyset$(Although both are good)

Comment: Let me explain my reasoning behind the statement *It suffices to generate bijection for each sequence as follows* ^^

Comment: @LeAnhDung sorry, I am not quite sure what did you mean in that comment

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm typing a comment.

Comment: In the proof, I defined three bijections $h:A_1 \to B_1$, $k:B_2 \to A_2$, and $t:A_3 \to B_3$. At the first of the proof, I reasoned that $\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$ is a partition of $A$ and $\{B_1,B_2,B_3\}$ is a partition of $B$. So $h\cup k\cup t$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung but this is wrong, that is possible that there are hundred separate A-stoppers, or $\aleph_{\aleph_1}$ separate Doubly infinite, what will you do then?

Comment: Can you be specific of which statement I got wrong? I'm quite not able to follow your previous comment.

Comment: @LeAnhDung how do you know that $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3=A$? There are 3 **type** of sequences, but there need not be 3 sequences **in total**, maybe there are 2 disjoint A-stopper sequences?

Comment: Now I got your point. Would it be better if I created a bijection for each sequence and took the union of all such bijections?

Comment: @LeAnhDung yes, notice that what I wrote in the post is exactly this but just formal

Comment: Please elaborate on: $P$ is a partition of which set? What is $Q$?

Comment: @LeAnhDung $P$ is partition that created from the sequences for $A\cup B$. In the first set($P_A$) $Q$ is arbitrary set such that if $x$ is a subset of $Q$ and $Q$ is a subset of $\bigcup P(=A\cup B)$ then $Q\setminus x$ has no element of $A$, in $P_B$ it is the same but with $B$ at the end

Comment: @LeAnhDung you can look at $P_A, P_B$ as take an element in $P$, take it's elements that in $A$ and put that set in $P_A$ and the set of the rest to $P_B$

Comment: Just for my curious, why don't use denote $\bigcup P$ directly by $A\cup B$?

Comment: @LeAnhDung to show the connection to $P$

Comment: May be I wrong. In your definition of $P_A,P_B$ there is nowhere that partition $P$ generated by such sequences appears. So how is $P$ related to the proof?

Comment: @LeAnhDung sorry I didn't make it clear: the definition of $P$ is the partition generated from the sequences!

Comment: Would it be fine if I defined $$P_A=\{x\in \mathcal P(A\cup B)\mid \exists y\in P(x=y\setminus B)\}$$ $$P_B=\{x\in \mathcal P(A\cup B)\mid \exists y\in P(x=y\setminus A)$$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83218/discussion-between-holo-and-le-anh-dung).